# How to access my GCP VM on localhost:3000

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, virtual-machine, metabase

I have Metabase running through a Docker image on a Google Compute Engine. The application defaults to port localhost:3000 however, I can't seem to figure out how to access this port on the Google VM.

I tried accessing the VM through `gcloud compute ssh {VM-NAME} --project={PROJECT} --zone={ZONE}` and this works. I used the `--troubleshoot` option as well (no problems) and setup Firewall rules to make the VM accessible on TCP ports 22 and 3000

Note:
I am a starting Data Engineer and just start to grasps the different concepts surrounding cloud computing, storage & networking. I think the problem must be somewhere surrounding the way I try to reach the Virtual Machine, however, I am unsure of where the problem lies exactly and I can't seem to find the solution online. I hope someone here can help me in the right direction so I can continue my learning journey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many steps to check to achieve what you want to achieve:

- Is the port 3000 accessible directly from the VM?

  - If not, it's because you did not forward the container port to the VM port. For that, you can perform `docker run -p <containerPort>:<VMPort> ...`, here use `-p 3000:3000` for instance
- If the port is accessible from the VM, be sure that the VM is publicly accessible (public IP).

  - If not, add an ephemeral public IP on your VM. Or more complex and expensive (but more secure) add a TCP load balancer in front of it.
- Be sure your firewall rules are in place.

Comment: Thanks for this! The solution was indeed to add a ephemeral public IP within the same zone and then add a firewall rule to that network that allows ingress access on port 3000. I did have the firewall rule, however, it was not linked to the network the VM used.